# Unknown Fieldtype String used in QueryElevationComponent

Tags: solr, indexing, jetty

I am using DataImporter to index MySQL records, but whenever I am running on browser it gives me this error.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unknown FieldType: 'string' used in QueryElevationComponent,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unknown FieldType: 'string' used in QueryElevationComponent
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:785)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown FieldType: 'string' used in QueryElevationComponent
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:524)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:559)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown FieldType: 'string' used in QueryElevationComponent
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:169)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:601)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:829)
    ... 13 more
,code=500}
```

here is my Schema.xml file. as this simple because I am just beginner to the SOLR.

```
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
   <types>
      <fieldtype name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
      <fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
      <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
   </types>



   <fields>
        <field name="user_id" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  />
        <field name="user_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   </fields>

   <uniqueKey>user_id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

and here is my db-data-config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<dataConfig>
       <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solr_user"
                   user="root"
                   password="waseem"
                   batchSize="-1" />
       <document name="user">
         <entity name="user" query="SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users">
            <field column="user_id" name="id" />
            <field column="user_name" name="name" />
         </entity>
     </document>
</dataConfig>
```

can anyone please tell me what's wrong in the above code and why I am getting this error. any help would be appreciated. I am using jetty on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following line "column" should be same as column name in your query and "name" is what you want to use. And name should match with schema.xml

```
 <field column="user_id" name="id" />
```

You need to make this change in your schema.xml. Name of the field in schema.xml should be same as field name in data-config.xml.

```
   <fields>
        <field name="id" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"  />
        <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" />
   </fields>
```

and i dont see any *version* field in your SQL query, so i dont know what you are trying to use here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply, when I don't use that version in my schema I am getting this error Unable to use updateLog: _version_ field must exist in schema. so that's what i am using and I am new to Solr.

Comment: Thanks it works. I have only three records in db but it takes too long to fetch it, do you have any idea what's going wrong with it ?

Comment: If it's only three records, it should not take more than a minute at any cost. Can you put your Schema.xml and solrConfig.xml somewhere and give me link, i can have a look at it. Also you can try removing batchSize parameter as it is useful when you have large data to fetch from database and batchSize param avoids java heap exception by fetching small data every time processing it and committing it.

Comment: here is the link for these files https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7137753. is I really need to have _version_ column in every schema ?

Comment: No, you never have to have version in your schema. I see that your schema.xml is very small and i have a bigger schema.xml which contains many tokenizers and filter which determined how your data will be tokenized and what all filterings you can apply (you may want to read about it if you need more info). But you are using solr 4.5 and i am still using 3.6, so that might make a difference. Well i have no idea about 4.5 but i am still sharing my schema.xml @ https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5imwxom2y9r84em/luln92Kl91/schema.xml , take a look, you might find something.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have seen that you are using default Schema.xml, quite sure it works fine without any issues if we use default schema.xml file.

Comment: yes, you just need to make changes for your fields, unique field and default search field. Later you can try to use different data types for your fields based of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `text` type to `string` like

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

that will fix the error message, but I would strongly recommend to reuse the existing solr example `schema.xml` and just edit the fields according to your needs.

You will not be able to benefit from Solr search if you do not include complex types of fields that make use of  Analyzers and Filters.

Comment: I have renamed the fields as you said, now I am getting undefined field text exception.

Comment: also you need to change the type of user_id... to string

Comment: Yeah i have changed it to string.

Comment: the most straightforward solution will be to reuse the schema from example(or at least use the defined types) and adjust the fields